# Objects are cropped/flicker during animation

Tags: jquery, animation

I have simultaneous animations that are all written like below. Basically, if you scroll down, the logo and nav bar shrink. All of the animations function, except while the logo is changing size, its bottom is briefly cropped off, as if the .site_header white bar is over top of it. Does anyone know what the problem is?

```
$(function(){
$('.header_image img').data('size','big');
});

$(window).scroll(function(){
if($(document).scrollTop() > 0)
{
if($('.header_image img').data('size') == 'big')
{
    $('.header_image img').data('size','small');
    $('.header_image img').stop().animate({
        width:'40px',
        height:'40px',
        topMargin:'5px'
    },600);
  }
}
else
{
if($('.header_image img').data('size') == 'small')
  {
    $('.header_image img').data('size','big');
    $('.header_image img').stop().animate({
        height:'80px',
        width:'80px'
    },600);
  }  
}
});
```

Just scroll up and down repeatedly to see what I'm talking about. Website is http://minimographite.com/

Comment: I notice that `overflow` is being set to `hidden` briefly. Not sure where it gets set though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kinda a hacky fix to be used for the `<div class="site-header">` style:

```
overflow-x: visible !important;
overflow-y: visible !important;
```

The root problem seems to be the `overflow` temporarily set to `hidden`.